# Netbeans with CodeIgniter: Variable "seems to be uninitialized" warning appears when it shouldn't

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans

In Netbeans 7.2 and CodeIgniter 2.1.2, variables inside of "views" always trigger a warning, "Variable $var seems to be uninitialized."

In this case, $var is defined in the usual way, when the view loaded in the controller:

```
$data["var"] = 'Some Value';
$this->load->view('main_page', $data);
```

And then referenced in the view in the usual way as well:

```
<p>the value is <?php echo $var; ?></p>
```

The code is working and functioning as expected, but in Netbeans, the line will trigger a warning, "Variable $var seems to be uninitialized."

The really weird thing is that autocomplete will actually suggest $var as I'm writing the view. So somehow autocomplete knows about it, but error checking doesn't.

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening, or at least suppress these kind of inaccurate warnings?

Comment: neglect it , its just a warning , we all get it in the scenrio you have mentioned , its because $var is not specified in the class

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this warning you can do this:

```
$data = array();

$data["var"] = 'Some Value';
$this->load->view('main_page', $data);
```

OR

```
$data["var"] = 'Some Value';

$this->load->vars($data);
$this->load->view('main_page');
```